# accelerate application with a faster clock in c# or c++

Tags: c#, c++, architecture, operating-system

I have different applications written in C# and C++ that communicate between each other. I would like to test this environment with some scenarios that I wrote.

Each scenario runs for different hours.

Is there a way to accelerate everything in order to have the scenarios run in minutes.

The applications may contains some `Thread.Sleep(...)` or equivalent in C++.

My idea is that a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` would wait for 2 seconds normally but when accelerated it should only wait for 200 ms.

Unfortunately I cannot change or refactor the code of the applications.

A first idea I have is to run the applications in an "accelerated Windows" system. A sort of wrapper of the OS where time run faster. But I have no idea on how to achieve this.

So any new idea or solution would be great.

Thanx

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not clear.  The simple solution is to reduce the amount of time a given task takes.

Comment: @Joachim, I didn't knew how to accept answers. Sorry about that.. Now I know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think "making Windows run faster" is practical, but I would consider intercepting the Sleep() method calls and short-circuiting them. I haven't looked, but Thread.Sleep() will probably thunk down somewhere to a Win32 API or an NT API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx).

You can use depends.exe from the Windows SDK and a debugger to see what your code uses, but I suspect (unless you know otherwise) that it won't simply be a Sleep() call, it'll more likely be a call waiting on some system object, I/O or a trigger, using WaitForMultipleObjectsEx() and friends.

Have a look at Detours from Microsoft Research for API interception http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx

There are are also various writings by Jeffry Richter and Matt Pietrek on the subject. In fact here's a codeproject article inspired by one of those;

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5178/DLL-Injection-and-function-interception-tutorial

Comment: I share your reservations.  It would be a miserable exercise that has a high probability of screwing up the overall functionality:(